# Stop the autoscroll in scrollview on user interaction swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I using the pagecontroller in my application.

it is working fine every thing it will scroll automatically for every 3 sec time and current position also changed based on user custom swipe.

But I having one issue here when user manually swipe the scrollview on that time I want to stop the auto scroll.

Please find with the my following code.

```
var slides:[Slide] = [];
var offSet: CGFloat = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    slides = createSlides()
    setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)

    pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    view.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

@objc func autoScroll() {
    let totalPossibleOffset = CGFloat(slides.count - 1) * self.view.bounds.size.width
    if offSet == totalPossibleOffset {
        offSet = 0 // come back to the first image after the last image
    }
    else {
        offSet += self.view.bounds.size.width
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
            self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = CGFloat(self.offSet)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: check with currentPage and slides array count

Answer (score 0):

Add scroll view delegate and use `scrollViewDidEndDragging` methods when it calls just reset your timer so after 3 sec start again it working as it is.

Comment: No I use this code it don't working func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 500, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

Comment: timer.invalidate() first invalidate your timer then start it again 
time interval is 500?

Answer (score 0):

The code is untested, You should check with current index with your total number slides count

Create one global index like below and change your conditions. And you need to manage this index while swipe function as well and **Invalidate** your timer while swipe. Your timer object should be in global

```
timer.invalidate()



 var currentPage = 0
        @objc func autoScroll() {
            let totalPossibleOffset = 0
            if currentPage == slides.count {
                currentPage = 0 // come back to the first image after the last image
                totalPossibleOffset = 0
            }
            else {
currentPage = currentPage + 1
                totalPossibleOffset = currentPage * self.view.bounds.size.width

            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
                    self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = CGFloat(totalPossibleOffset)
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```